# How can I override the way Proxies are displayed in console?

Tags: javascript, proxy

I've looked through the docs on Proxies, and there is a long list of function properties which can be overridden.  Unfortunately, none of them explicitly mention a link to console.log(), and I can't infer which ones console.log() might interact with.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

I've also seen this Stack Overflow question ([Javascript Proxy and spread syntax, combined with console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106122/javascript-proxy-and-spread-syntax-combined-with-console-log)) which seems to show something similar to what I'm looking for, but more targeted at getting information about a property than the way it's displayed in console.

The issue is, whenever I console.log my proxies, I get output like this:

> Proxy { <target>: {…}, <handler>: {…} }

Further, my target is (in my case) totally empty.

```js
const foo = { foo: "foo string" };
const bar = { bar: "bar string" };

let currentObj = foo;

const proxy = new Proxy({}, {
  get: (_, prop) => currentObj[prop],
});

console.log(proxy.foo);
console.log(proxy); // would like this to be { foo: "foo" }

currentObj = bar;
console.log(proxy.bar);
console.log(proxy); // would like this to be { bar: "bar" }
```

So, in order to make this code possible to debug, I need some way to tell console.log what object to output.

**Is it possible to override some aspect of a Proxy handler such that console.log() will output arbitrary, use-case specific data?**

Comment: You cannot overwrite how any object is displayed in the console - you can't do it for proxies either.

Comment: I assume you're on the browser, using chrome devtools for `console.log`?

Comment: I'm making a tool for others to use, so I'm trying not to be browser specific.  But, my case is FF devtools.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the toString method and log your object with its toString() method.

Or you could provide a different view-specific log function such as `oob.log => () => obj.name`